# Generate progressively larger random tokens as they become used up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the "before_create" callback in one of my models to generate a unique random string.

```
def generate_shortcut
  if !self.shortcut
    self.shortcut = loop do
      random_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(5, false)
      break random_token unless Url.exists?(shortcut: random_token)
    end
  end
end
```

I imagine that once more of the available tokens are taken, it'll take longer to generate a unique one? As well as when they've all been taken.

Is there any way to increment the value in "SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(x, false) when this happens without having to do it manually?

Comment: You can use `uuid` instead of `urlsafe_base64`. Although the probability of a repeated UUID is not 0, it is very low, so that you shouldn't worry about the generation time becoming longer over the lifetime of the application. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates

Comment: On a separate note, these are all strings, so use [`succ`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-succ) to increment the value. Note how it increments digits to digits and alphanums to alhapnums keeping the case (meaning that `"...az".succ` will result in `"...ba"`). You may want to account for special cases, like uuids/base64 ending in all '9's and 'z's after the last dash - calling `succ` on that would increment the dash char. But you can catch it with a simple regex and substitute, say, all '0's  after the last dash in that case.